# Applications downloaded from the Internet

Tags: apt, software-center, ppa, downloads

Is there any way when installing an application from the internet to automatically add the repository on the software manager so it can auto update and also see what's installed on my system? Because if i download something outside the software center it doesn't show up on "my installed applications" section. The problem is that most of the times the websites don't have the PPA written somewhere. Also is there any legit list with PPA's after UBUNTU's fresh installation??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It depends on the application. For example, Google-Chrome, and Skype downloaded from the Internet will automatically add the PPAs to your source list. It may help if you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1070166/edit) your question and specify which applications you have downloaded and what problems you are having.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "legit list with PPA's" because that's not what PPAs are intended for. PPAs were originally created for testing, not widespread distribution. PPAs (with a few exceptions) are supported by the PPA maintainer, not us. We created a tool that keeps track of Ubuntu Software. For non-Ubuntu software, you are on your own.

Comment: Skype for example is a widespread application so it's PPA is "legit".

Comment: If you install apps outside software center or apt you are on your own. @Emmanouil Syathis "legit" is subjective.  I think the points about ppa are: 1. They are unofficial and bug reports go to the ppa owners not the ubuntu developers. 2. Not everyone uses them, for example I do not use Skype. 3. There is thus no official list of ppa to use anywhere, let alone in the software center